# Java EE and JBOoss EAP 6.3

Tags: java, oracle, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I'm new to the JBoss application server and I tried to add a datasource for an Oracle db in JBoss EAP6.3. But I am getting the error below and seeing error while 'Testing a db connection in server'.

Please let me know if I have missed something.

Step 1-> Added below datasource in standalone.xml file
Step 2-> Created a module.xml file and placed under \modules folder as com\oracle\main
Here is my module.xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.oracle">
<resources>
 <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
</resources>
   <dependencies>
 <module name="javax.api"/>
  <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
 </module>
```

Step 3-> Copied a ojdbc6.jar file in the com\oracle\main location.

Step 4-> Started the server by standalone.bat file

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XS</connection-url>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>system</user-name>
                    <password>system</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle">
                    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

---

### Error on console:

```
  Unexpected HTTP response: 500

  Request
{
"address" => [
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "OracleDS")
],
"operation" => "test-connection-in-pool"
 }

 Response

 Internal Server Error
{
"outcome" => "failed",
 "failure-description" => "JBAS010440: failed to invoke operation:        JBAS010447: Connection is not valid",
"rolled-back" => true
```

}

please help me out how to create a connection ,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Place your `ojdbc6.jar in $JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/oracle/jdbc/main/` along with your module.xml.

> The path where you have placed your ojdbc6.jar and module.xml is not
>   correct.
>   It should be modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/main

Also define the data-source definition like:-

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XS</connection-url>
                <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>system</user-name>
                    <password>system</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                 <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle"/>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer .i tried as you mentioned as above and im still facing the same error even after placing the ojdbc6.jar and module .xml in modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/main

Comment: Try to make connection in SQL developer or any other SQL ide just to ensure the credentials and db url you are putting is correct and nothing specific to jboss.

Comment: now the db connection is successfully bounded in jboss web console .when i tried to establish a connection from eclipse after starting the server via command prompt ,it is throwing the below error:                                                  JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report

JBWEB000068: message /DBT/

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Remove the JBOSS server configuration from eclipse and again import it in eclipse. Sometimes it caches old configurations.

Comment: after re configuring the server still facing the below exception.it would be very great full if you could help me out from this.

Comment: Exception inthread"main"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source
 at dbt.TestDBConnection.main(TestDBConnection.java:11

Comment: Try to create a datasource through the JBOSS console, which internally changes standalone.xml and adds the resouce.  Changing the standalone.xml sometimes doesn't work.